# ExtJS accordion init component while collapsed

Tags: extjs, init

I have following problem in EXTJS:
I have an accordion layout with 2 panels.
the first panel is for choosing an element and if you doubleclick the detail will be displayed in the second panel.

However there is one problem:
The elements of panel2 seems not to be initialised, so i get an "is undefined" error.

When i open panel2 and close it, i dont have the problem.
However opening and closing it looks creepy.

Is there a way to initialise the elements while it is collapsed?
or is there something like a callback in mainPanel.layout.setActiveItem(panel1)...callback:initPanel2() ?

Answer (score 1):

Both panels should already be rendered (unless you have set `deferredRender: true`) so it's unclear exactly what you are trying to do.  What does your code look like?

Comment: ok i noticed, that it renders some elements: the main elements.
However it doesnt render the underelements like radio buttons.

I have one RadioGroup and i cannot access the radio Button within the radio gruop, before i open the accordion.

But i have also a Textfield and i can access the Textfield without opening the panel.

Is there a way to init the underlings?